# HTML and CSS layout not showing properly on smartphone

Tags: html, css, mobile

[image]

I am trying to use a free web template. But I cannot figure out how can I fix the background image. Does anyone give an idea to solve this problem. I wanted to show the code but don't know which part to give.. I can show this on desktop with no problem.

Comment: can you please provide a link

Comment: as a side note: study responsive design .. if you want your application to look properly on mobile

Comment: is it because ipad magnified the design and you did everything precisely in pixels?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the `height & width = 100%` also div's too

Answer (score 0):

Try having a look at the css3 background property

```
html { 
       background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
      -webkit-background-size: cover;
      -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
       background-size: cover;
     }
```

I am sure it solves your purpose.

Have a look this link for detailed info

> http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Also as Syed mentioned, study about responsive design or stick to some framework like Bootstrap.